cannot POST via powershell to simple HTML form
I'm not able to get webpost.ps1 to POST to the http server I have but manually, the login form works and writes to data.txt. It returns with status 200 OK but I'm not sure why this isn't actually POSTing to data.txt because other sources show this code should work as I have googled it and even followed instructions based off the Invoke-WebRequest module on microsoft.com
====== foobar.html ==============
<form action="parser.php" method="post">
  <label for="field1">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" value=""><br>
  <label for="field2">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


====== parser.php ===============
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . ':' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('data.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}


====== webpost.ps1 ==============
$params = @{
field1 = 'John'
field2 = 'Doe'
}

$Uri = 'http://u.r.l/foobar.html'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method POST -Body $params


Have you been able to get it working with other tools - e.g. Postman / curl? Can you add the details to your question if so? And if you run a MitM proxy like Fiddler in the background to capture raw HTTP requests (or look in Chrome Dev Tools), what does the working web browser POST look like? Also, if there's a login form in the web browser you'll probably need to incorporate that in your PowerShell script as well as a sequence of requests - the chances are there's an auth token or session cookie of some sort from the login page needed in your POST to authenticate it...

I was able to get this to work by submitting it directly via parser.php and not foobar.html but I'm not sure if this is truly the correct answer
